# CSS animation does not work in Chrome

Tags: css

The Code below does not seem to work in Chrome. How can we get this code to run in Chrome?

```
h1 {
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-name: slidein;
    font-size:36px;
    color:#7D1212;
}
@keyframes slidein {
    from {
        margin-left: 100%;
        width: 300%;
    }
    to {
        margin-left: 0%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    75% {
        font-size: 300%;
        margin-left: 25%;
        width: 150%;
    }
}
```

Comment: how you found its not supported

Answer (score 0):

SlideIn doesn't exist as animation, but you would probably use something like this to add a similar animation to the one you'd like to achive:

http://jsfiddle.net/tf81mxn2/

using `BounceInLeft;`  instead of slideIn.